# Is resistance to motion directly proportional to the speed of a moving object?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, power, work, drag

Power is known to be equal to the force x velocity (P=FV).

Im solving a question that states the following :

Car with engine working at 32 kW, mass of 1 tonne, travels at a constant speed of 40m/s along a level road.

**Given that the resistance to motion is directly proportional to the speed at which the car is travelling**, find the resistance experienced when the car is travelling at 30m/s

How is the text in **Bold** correct ?? P=FV .. Which means F=P/V, Velocity(speed) of car is indirectly proportional to the Force !! Can someone please explain this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are stating that as part of the question, not stating that it's necessarily true. You often see things like "ignoring air resistance", a "frictionless plane" or "massless spring" as part of questions to allow a simple analytical answer.

in reality for a car moving at 40 m/s air resistance is likely to be the major source of drag and this is proportional to velocity^2, but this makes the resulting equations trickier